# Newton Raphson Method 2D in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, newtons-method

I've been working in this code of Newton Raphson based in some ideas of the 1D case, now I'm trying to turn it to multiple variables in Python for two coupled equations.

I'm not sure if it is working ok, first it seems to obtain the result at first iteration, second it tends to give slightly different result.

Is it ok? How do I can tell if it is not. Thanks.

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import *
from scipy import linalg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x, y, z = symbols('x y z')
init_printing(use_unicode=True)

w0=1
B=1
f=0.1
delta=1
d=0.1

w=np.array([0.5,0.75,1,1.25,1.5,1.75,2,2.25,2.5,2.75,3])

A1f=np.zeros(11)
A2f=np.zeros(11)

i=0

for i in range(len(w)):
    A1=input('A1=')
    A2=input('A2=')

    u1=w0**2.-w[i]**2.+delta+(3.*B/4.)*x
    u2=w0**2.-w[i]**2.+delta+(3.*B/4.)*y


    f1=(y**2)*(u2**2+(w[i]**2)*d**2)-(x**2)*delta**2


    f2=(x**2)*(u1**2+(d**2)*w[i]**2)+(2.*(d**2)*w[i]**2+delta**2)*y**2-2.*u1*u2*y**2-f**2

    dxf1=diff(f1,x).evalf(subs={x:A1, y:A2})
    dyf1=diff(f1,y).evalf(subs={x:A1, y:A2})

    dxf2=diff(f2,x).evalf(subs={x:A1, y:A2})
    dyf2=diff(f2,y).evalf(subs={x:A1, y:A2})

    J=np.array([[float(dxf1), float(dyf1)],[float(dxf2), float(dyf2)]])


    Jinv=linalg.inv(J)

    n=1
    TOL=0.0001
    NMAX=100

    F=np.array([f1.evalf(subs={x:A1, y:A2}), f2.evalf(subs={x:A1, y:A2})])


    def inner_prod(v1, v2):
     'inner production of tw[i]o vectors.'
     sum = 0
     for i in xrange(len(v1)):
            sum += v1[i] * v2[i]
     return sum

    def matmult3(m, v):
     'matrix multiply vector by inner production.'
     return [inner_prod(r, v) for r in m]


    while n <= NMAX:
        n+=1
        H=matmult3(Jinv,F)
        D=np.array([A1,A2])-H
        x2=D[0]
        y2=D[1]
        if x2-A1<TOL and y2-A2<TOL:
            print x2, y2
            A1f[i]=x2
            A2f[i]=y2
        else:
            x0=x
            y0=y

plt.plot(w, A1f,'x', w, A2f, 'x')
plt.show()
```

Thanks, for checking it.

Comment: Maybe this question is better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com. Otherwise maybe you should provide input and expected output.

Comment: This is totally wrong, problem solved. Ask me if you want the NR N-variables in Python. :)